# longtable(tabu) with multirow and page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, multirow, tabu

I'm trying to place a bunch of images into the multirow within **longtabu**. But it looks messy if row is splitted by page break. The same problem with long text in multirow. Neither image nor text are not moved to another page.

Is there way to make it correct?
Thanks!

PS my environment: win, texlive 2013, xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, longtable, tabu, graphicx}

\begin{document}    
\section{Section}
\vspace{16cm} % to force page break.

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|c|X[m]|}
\cline{1-2}\endhead

\cline{1-2}\endfoot

\cline{1-2}    
\multirow{9}{60pt}{
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=30pt]{image.eps} 
    \includegraphics[height=30pt]{image.eps}
    %Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    \end{center}
} &1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[Image for testing (image.eps)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4571566/image.eps)
[image]

Comment: you can't split the cell over a page so you need to manually change that multirow and put one image in something spanning the first 5 rows and one in a second span for the later rows. Not ideal, but it will get the doc done...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, didn't think of this scenario; pretty hard to implement since I generate tex files by script, but anyway your proposal is useful.

Comment: If you use `\multirow{9}`, the next eight ``\\`` must be ``\\*``

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If it's possible to convert your comment to answer I may accept it. Probably it's the only way without diving into TeX programming.
To @egreg yep I'm using `\\*` for all spanned rows except last to allow page breaks between multirows, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't split the cell over a page so you need to manually change that `\multirow` and put one image in something spanning the first 5 rows and one in a second span for the later rows. Not ideal, but it will get the doc done...